# Quiz Application with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Alright. I am a beginner and I am unable to find a solution to this problem. I am developing this quizzing application. I have built the part that allows you to create and manage questions classified by difficulty and tags. But Im not able to think of a proper quiz logic.

I want a single page with question numbers and one question displayed at a time. And I want to be able to move back and forth by clicking the numbers and I should have some way of indicating the attempted questions. Then I need an option for a timer that would submit the questions automatically.

I really really don't know where to start. I found this [Reexaminator](http://rexaminator.com/) site. It has what I want except for the timer.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

This is what I built finally. This is a demo app. It has lots of UI issues and some bugs. Just for reference if someone needs.

http://rtester.herokuapp.com/

Would be nice if someone would answer the Original Question. Thanks.
Its for my college.

Comment: Have you checked out https://github.com/schneems/wicked ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks interesting.

Comment: Well wicked needs us to specify the number of stages. But the number of questions is decided dynamically.

Comment: This might seem irrelevant, but what is this project for? A client? Yourself, for fun? Homework? I have some advice, but it depends on the purpose of the project.

Comment: Also, I just realized this question is almost a year old. Good thing I didn't invest a bunch of time in writing an answer! (I will if OP responds to my question.)

Comment: @JasonSwett I stumbled upon this question. My condition is similar these days. My quizzing application is for a client. It would be great help to have your answer.

Comment: I built an app with all questions in one page. and added a sidebar for question numbers. Would be nice to see how to do it the other way. @JasonSwett will you please? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question with many possible solutions for each of the features that you are describing. The answer can vary widely depending on the organization of your app and the relationships between your models, i.e., `Quiz` and `Question`.

For starters, you'd like a navigation bar that allows you to view each question.

You could iterate over the quiz numbers like so:

```
<ul>
  @question.each do |question|
    <li><%= link_to question.number, question %></li>
  end
</ul>
```

That would provide a list of links, each displayed as a number, but linking to the #show action and view of your `Question` model/resource.